# Tidy Eval: Using {{var}} inside a nesting function not possible?

Tags: r, metaprogramming, tidyverse, rlang, tidyeval

I was trying to use `tidyr::complete` inside my function while providing the variable names using `{{}}`. This works fine, however, when I add a nesting function to combine two variables I get an error. Please see the minimal example below.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

df <- tibble(
  group1 = c(1:2, 1),
  group2 = c("c", "c", "c"),
  item_id = c(1:2, 2),
  item_name = c("a", "b", "b"),
  value1 = 1:3,
  value2 = 4:6
)

my_complete <- function(data, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6){
  data %>%
    tidyr::complete({{var1}}, {{var3}})
}

my_complete(df, var1 = group1, var2 = group2, var3 = item_id, var4 = item_name, var5 = value1, var6 = value2)
```

This works and the output is:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 6
  group1 item_id group2 item_name value1 value2
   <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>  <chr>      <int>  <int>
1      1       1 c      a              1      4
2      1       2 c      b              3      6
3      2       1 NA     NA            NA     NA
4      2       2 c      b              2      5
```

When I however combine two variables with nesting I get an error.

```
my_complete_nesting <- function(data, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6){
  data %>%
    tidyr::complete(nesting({{var1}}, {{var2}}), nesting({{var3}}, {{var4}}))
}

my_complete_nesting(df, var1 = group1, var2 = group2, var3 = item_id, var4 = item_name, var5 = value1, var6 = value2)
```

```
 Error in .f(.x[[i]], ...) : object 'group1' not found
```

Maybe I am missing something but I can just not get it to work. I thought I understood how to use `{{}}`. When I use the alternative expression of `variable <- enquo(variable)` and `!!variable` I get the same problem. So it is not specifically `{{}}` that is causing the problem but rather the way I use tidy eval here.
I would like to get the following output:

```
df %>%
  tidyr::complete(nesting(group1, group2), nesting(item_id, item_name))

# A tibble: 4 x 6
  group1 group2 item_id item_name value1 value2
   <dbl> <chr>    <dbl> <chr>      <int>  <int>
1      1 c            1 a              1      4
2      1 c            2 b              3      6
3      2 c            1 a             NA     NA
4      2 c            2 b              2      5
```

I would really appreciate some help with this problem. Maybe I am just missing something simply but I cannot seem to find the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is actually an example where you **don't** want to use quosures. A quosure captures an expression as well as the context where it should be evaluated. In your case, it captures the global environment, where **group1 is not defined**. This is why you get an "object not found" error, when `nesting()` attempts to resolve the expression.

Because you want `group1` to be evaluated in the context of the data frame (and not in the global context), the proper mechanism to use here is `ensym()`:

```
my_complete_nesting <- function(data, var1, var2, var3, var4, var5, var6){
  data %>%
    tidyr::complete(nesting(!!ensym(var1), !!ensym(var2)), 
                    nesting(!!ensym(var3), !!ensym(var4)))

}

## Now works
my_complete_nesting(df, var1 = group1, var2 = group2, 
                    var3 = item_id, var4 = item_name, 
                    var5 = value1, var6 = value2)
```